# Wordpress custom post loop for slider

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

How can i make looping for this slider :
My Slider looks like : http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/969867/a3a51b333881ca762739151dae8b16f9

First li consist of top image and second one comes with below one. each single image must be a single post

Html Code :

```
<div class="row cycle-slideshow" data-cycle-fx=carousel data-cycle-timeout=0 data-cycle-carousel-visible=3 data-cycle-carousel-fluid=true data-cycle-slides="li" data-cycle-next="#next" data-cycle-prev="#prev" data-cycle-pager="#pager">
    <ul>

        <li class="span2">
            <a href="#journeymodel">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/">
                <h3>Barobudur Temple, java</h3>
                <div></div>
            </a>
            <a href="#journeymodel">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/">
                <h3>Barobudur Temple, java</h3>
                <div></div>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="span2">
            <a href="#journeymodel">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/">
                <h3>Uluvatu Temple, Bali</h3>
                <div></div>
            </a>
            <a href="#journeymodel">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/">
                <h3>Uluvatu Temple, Bali</h3>
                <div></div>
            </a>
        </li>
```

Php code :

```
<?php
    $loop = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'realisation','sort_column' => 'post_date','posts_per_page'=> -1);//'order' => 'DESC'); 
        if ( $loop->have_posts() ) 
        {
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) 
              {
                $loop->the_post();
                $cat=get_post_meta($post->ID,'category',true);
                if ($cat=='privae')  // post catagory
              {
             //li section should comes here by based on list of post added
```

Can someone guide me how can i update the looping for this section .

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
$arr = array("post_type" => "post_type", 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'orderby' => 'post_title', 'order' => 'ASC');
$posts= get_posts($arr);

echo '<ul>';
foreach($posts as $post) {
    $img= get_post_meta($post->ID, 'meta_field', true);
    echo "<li><img src='" . $img . "' /></li>";
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: Yes my question is how can i add my li section into loop to get the slider images get dynamic from my custom post

Comment: Ok I am testing still i am not able to get the exact result on this, Will get you back once get works

Comment: Ok, let me know what problem you are getting if you want.

Comment: I am still get stuck with the above section , Actually i will let you know the whole flow of this part .
I have double slider which i have shown in the screenshot , one single <li> consist of two images with an popup , then next single li consist of two images . Each images has a custom  popup content, And I need to  get the the post based on category selection, I have created a custom field with dropdown that has three category. If want to get only one category on this template and another two cataogory on another template page, Please check php code  which i have added above .